# add payment method on account creation page magento

Tags: magento

How to add payment methods on `/index.php/customer/account/create/` i.e. on customer account creation page on magento. The main motive is to allow the customer to use simple account creation on magento website and allow them to save the payment method of later use.

I did not found any clues for adding the available payment method to show on account creation step on magento.

Hope someone has answer.